# Insert the values through a stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following code in Sql server, kindly let me know what is the appropriate code of inserting values through a stored procedure in oracle:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERTPRODUCTRECORD
(
 @PNAME VARCHAR(5),
 @CATEGORY VARCHAR(50),
   @PRICE INT
    )
   AS
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PNAME,PRICE,CATEGORY)
     VALUES(@PNAME, @CATEGORY, @PRICE INT)
      END
```

Comment: Does this code fail in some way?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting when you are trying to execute this procedure?

Comment: You need to set input parameters else each time when you call the procedure it will will insert the same value..

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERTPRODUCTRECORD (p_PNAME VARCHAR2, p_CATEGORY VARCHAR2, p_PRICE NUMBER) 
AS 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PNAME,PRICE,CATEGORY) VALUES(p_PNAME, p_CATEGORY, p_PRICE); 
commit; 
END INSERTPRODUCTRECORD;
```

Comment: You have introduced a COMMIT statement.  That is probably undesirable, because transaction management is the perquisite of the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

```
VARCHAR(5)
```

- [Oracle highly recommends](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1835) to use **VARCHAR2** instead of **VARCHAR**.

> VARCHAR Datatype
>
> The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To
>   avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype
>   to store variable-length character strings.

```
PNAME VARCHAR(5)
```

- No need to mention the **size** of the parameter, only the **datatype** is enough.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERTPRODUCTRECORD(
    i_PNAME    VARCHAR2,
    i_CATEGORY VARCHAR2,
    i_PRICE    NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT
  INTO PRODUCT
    (
      PNAME,
      PRICE,
      CATEGORY
    )
    VALUES
    (
      i_PNAME,
      i_PRICE,
      i_CATEGORY
    )
END;
/
```